# Jekyll Help: for loops and offsets

Tags: jekyll, liquid

I'm building a blog theme with Jekyll but I've been stumped and could use some help.

**What I Want** Two columns, side by side, that each hold 2 article listings - 4 in total. (see image for context)

**The Problem** I'm not great with liquid and couldn't find a clear answer on for loops and iterators, nor could I find a switch statement example. The way that I have the code now makes it so both of these columns list the same exact articles, because the index isn't being carried over to the for loop for respective container.

Help? Thanks!

```
<div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 article-cards" id="first-column">
{% for post in site.categories.advice limit:2 %}
    <h5><a href="{{ post.url }}">{{ post.title }}</a></h5>
    <span class="date">{{ post.date | date: '%B %d, %Y' }}</span>
{% endfor %}
</div>

<div class="ol-xs-12 col-sm-6 article-cards push-down" id="first-column">
{% for post in site.categories.advice offset:2  limit:2 %}
    <h5><a href="{{ post.url }}">{{ post.title }}</a></h5>
    <span class="date">{{ post.date | date: '%B %d, %Y' }}</span>
{% endfor %}
</div>
```

[repository](https://github.com/ninapetrop/Jekyll-Testing-Site/tree/NewLayout)

[Image for context](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dReqY.png)

Comment: Cannot reproduce this behavior. Do you have a code repository ?

Comment: [repo](https://github.com/ninapetrop/Jekyll-Testing-Site/tree/NewLayout)